# Why does my program not output anything in the command window when I run it?

Tags: python, bubble-sort

So I defined a function for bubble sorting but when I try to run it I just get a blank console window. I feel like its something really stupid like a syntax error but I can't pin it down. Here is the code:

```
def bubble(arr):
swap = True 
while (swap == True):
    swap = False
    for i in range(len(arr)-1):
        temp = arr[i]
        if arr[i]> arr[i+1]:
            temp = arr[i+1]
            arr[1] = arr[i+1]
    swap = True

array = ["AB","AAB","AAA"]
print (bubble(array))
input()
```

Comment: What is the expected output ? the `bubble` function seem return nothing, so it's the expected behaviour

Comment: Can you confirm the indentation of your code please? Make sure that the way it is structured here is exactly as it is in your editor

Comment: There is no `return` value, and it is also getting stuck in an infinite loop

Comment: Your indentation is messed up `bubble` seems to lack any definition.

Comment: also the `while` condition will always be `True`. You need a break statement if you ever want it to halt

Comment: @idjaw: I already fixed the indentation, but you put it back.  I think it's pretty obvious what is in the function, so I saw no harm in editing it.  You do?

Comment: @zondo No. There are other issues with the code. It is best to leave the code as is and make the OP confirm what their code looks like. Typically, if it is just a matter of providing the proper code format for the SO question, then that's fine. But when you start editing code, that is a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a bubble function that will more likely work.

```
def bubble(arr):
    swap = True
    while (swap == True):
        swap = False
        for i in range(len(arr)-1):
            if arr[i]> arr[i+1]:
                arr[i], arr[i+1] = arr[i+1], arr[i]
                swap = True
    return arr
```

There are various issues in your original bubble function.

1. Your function does not return anything, so `print(bubble(array))` will always output `None`
2. Your second `swap = True` statement was ill-placed, and was executed at each step of your while loop, resulting in infinite loop
3. you wrote `arr[1] = arr[i+1]` instead of `arr[i] = arr[i+1]`, and forgot the second part of swapping. In python, you can swap two values without the need of a `temp` variable, which is what I've done.